# `UIRefreshControl endRefreshing` not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uirefreshcontrol

I've got a pull-to-refresh feature in my app that is, as far as I can tell, set up the "normal way":

```
UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
refreshControl.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Pull to Refresh"];

[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshPage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
self.refreshControl = refreshControl;
```

The refreshing part works fine.  After it is done refreshing I call

```
[self.refreshControl endRefreshing]
```

at which point, it appears to ignore that call and continues to show the pull-to-refresh "gap", only without the spinner:

[image: pull to refresh sticking]

(I do have a breakpoint at that line to verify that `endRefreshing` *IS* actually being called)

If I jiggle the page with my thumb (pull it down slightly without pulling it far enough to trigger another pull-to-refresh), it will fix itself and spring back into place.  But why doesn't it spring back when I call `[self.refreshControl endRefreshing]`?  Is there a way I can programmatically force it to spring back?

I've also tried placing the `endRefreshing` call in a delay:

```
[self.refreshControl performSelector:@selector(endRefreshing) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0]
```

but it still ignores the call.

Comment: If you're using IB, do you have the UITableView 'Refreshing' property set to Enabled?

Comment: @fbara - I'm using a Storyboard.  I'm not seeing a "Refreshing" property via the xcode UI, or via code...

Comment: Tap on the UITableViewController.  In Attributes Inspector there is a setting named 'Refreshing' and drop-down to select 'Enabled'.

Answer (score 11):

You could stop the `refreshControl` and reset the `tableview` position with an animation

```
self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
    yourTableview.contentOffset = CGPoint.zero
})
```

Comment: tampering with contentOffset will obscure the refreshControl still spinning

Answer (score 6):

It turns out, in my case, the problem was that the code for adding the `UIRefreshControl` was being hit more than once and creating more than one refreshControl, so `endRefreshing` was being called on a different instance of `UIRefreshControl` than the one that started the pull-to-refresh.

Dumb mistake on my part.

Answer (score 6):

For me setting `UITableView contentOffset` to zero, worked

In **Swift 3.0**

```
refreshControl.endRefreshing()
self.yourTableView.contentOffset = CGPoint.zero
```

Answer (score 0):

After call `refreshControl.endRefreshing()` property `isRefreshing = false`, but it can still be presented.  Problem is in layers - while other animation is in progress or view controller with refresh control is not visible (other vc is presented or key window changed to another one). The code below helped me to fix this problem

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) { [weak self] in
    guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
    if strongSelf.refreshControl.isRefreshing {
        strongSelf.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    } else if !strongSelf.refreshControl.isHidden {
        strongSelf.refreshControl.beginRefreshing()
        strongSelf.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    }
}
```